# rear deicer causes radio interference

Tags: audio

Last year snow and ice fell off my house and damaged my 2006 impala.The roof was replaced along with front and rear glass.Now when the rear deicer is on it causes radio interference.Returning it to the body shop would make sense if I had noticed it 14 months ago.

Comment: This almost sounds like the deicer is shorting to the condensation or the ice on the glass.  What happens when you turn the deicer on when everything is dry and warm?

Comment: Same effect wet or dry.

Answer (score 1):

Whereabouts on the car is the radio aerial located? I would suspect you have a crossed wire between the two, especially if the aerial is at the back of the roof or near the rear window (in which case the wire from that and the wire to the heater would be likely to follow the same path).

Unfortunately, it is probably a case of taking off the appropriate interior trim, and hunting for any damaged wires in the two circuits...

Comment: the aerial/antennae is in the front windshield,the deicer is the grid type embedded in the rear glass

Answer (score 0):

A bad ground or power connection can cause interference.  Check the attachment points.  Also check anyplace enroute where part of the defroster cable may have been pinched and damaged.